# Return false does not prevent form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have form that I need to validate using JavaScript and I need to show all the messages at the same time. E.g if the first name and surename is missing for two messages to appear. I've got this working with the below code but the form is still being returned back to the server. P Lease see below:

```
function validateForm() {
    var flag = true;
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["firstname_4"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        document.getElementById("fNameMessage").innerHTML = "First name is  required";
        flag = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("fNameMessage").innerHTML = "";
    }

    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["surname_5"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        document.getElementById("sNameMessage").innerHTML = "Surename is required";
        flag = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sNameMessage").innerHTML = "";
    }
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["selectid"];
    if (y.options[y.selectedIndex].value == "Title") {
        document.getElementById("titleMessage").innerHTML = "You need to select a title";
        flag = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("titleMessage").innerHTML = "";
    }

    return flag;
}
```

My form and event :

```
<form action=""method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

My Button:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I believe you mean 'surname' instead of 'surename'.  (Though I seriously doubt that is related to your problem)

Comment: Have you checked your browser's JavaScript console for error messages?

Comment: Do you need help to find your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: No Sorry, I'm getting this message Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined website_email_sign_up.html:32
validateForm website_email_sign_up.html:32
onsubmit and a post error of 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["selectid"];
if (y.options[y.selectedIndex].value == "Title")
```

... triggers an exception and you don't catch it:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Thus JavaScript code stops running.

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone seems to be providing jQuery answers and I didn't see anything in your orignal code that was jQuery-esque I'll assume you aren't using jQuery.

You should be using the event.preventDefault:

Sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener(
     "click", validateForm, false
);
function validateForm(){

    // We should not assume a valid form! 
    var formValid = false;

    // All your validation code goes here

    if(formValid){
        document.forms["myform"].submit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
if(flag){
   document.getElementById("submit").submit();
} 
else{
   $('#submit').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
}
```

Comment: might it be better to preventDefault conditionally based on the validateForm()?

Comment: Bear in mind this is a **jQuery** solution so if you aren't using jQuery, this won't work.

Comment: @user3334690 just edited the answer to as per your suggestion.

Comment: It's all in the head of the page and I've placed your code inside and outside the function but neither have worked. Where would you suggest?

Comment: you should take out the return at the end of the listed function and use the code there. and make aure to include the jquery lib

Comment: Tried this but still no luck